# Vscode Linting for property not work with .js but it works with .ts,Do you have this issue?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint

When I type For example `console.logsss` in VSCode with `.js` no error shows up but when I change it to `.ts` I got an error, why this simple thing not work with `.js` extension?

[image: js]
[image: ts]

Comment: console.log() is correct

Comment: i know but i intentionally writes console.logssss to see why i got no error , this is just not about console.log this is about method and property that .js not recognize them but .ts do.

Answer (score 0):

Check your config for lint. If you use node, add this to `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  ...,
  "lint": "eslint . --ext=js,jsx,ts",
  ...
}
```

Comment: VSCode won't automatically lint by having a script in package.json

Answer (score 0):

To have your JS checked the way TS is you have to either:

- enable "checkJs" `js/ts.implicitProjectConfig.checkJs` (previously `javascript.implicitProjectConfig.checkJs`) in workspace or user settings,
- use `// @ts-check` magic comment on top of your JS file.

See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_type-checking